# Is setting fields line after line from a Firestore document read an anti-pattern?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document on Firestore, from which I read its fields in a fragment. Since it has many fields, I set variables in the Activity that hosts this fragment so that I can pass the data between other fragments. In order to achieve that, I realize that I have to write similar lines of codes over and over again, which got me to thinking if there is a better way.
[image]

Two possible solutions that come to my mind:

- Structure all these fields in JSON format -> something that wouldn't be suitable in Firestore's document system imo
- Put all these fields into a serializable data class which I keep in the activity then pass it around the bundles of fragments -> Seemed to complicated and I would still have to write it.get(foo) as bar for each of the field's of this class' constructor.

Given all these, what is the best approach? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have a several options on how to approach this.  There is none that's necessarily better than another.  Ultimately, you will pick the one that best suits your needs and preferences.

1. You can do what you're doing now.
2. You can go a step further an actually check the types of the values instead of just blindly casting them (which would cause a crash at runtime if they didn't match).
3. You can provide a Class object to [get(String, Class<T>)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#toSet) that can automatically map the fields to properties in a new object of type T, as long as the types also match.
4. You can call a variety of type-specific versions of get, such as [getString()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getString(java.lang.String))

Ultimately you will have to decide if you are going to trust what you get in the snapshot and allow errors to happen, or trust nothing and check everything.  It's up to you.